# How can i read more than 2 lines in a text file? c#

Tags: c#

I am currently reading a text file using `File.ReadLines` into a `List<>`.
In order to identify the line I wish to read, I have identified the previous line, then in order to identify the string in that line, I used split string and output this to console. When I want to read more than 2 lines, I do not get the desired output, here is my code;

```
 List<string> _FileContents = File.ReadLines(path)ToList();

        string pLine = "";
        string previousTrack = "";
        string ppLine = "";

        foreach (string line in _FileContents)
        {
            if (pLine.Contains("Race"))
            {
                if (pLine.Contains("TOD")) { }
            }
            else
            {
                if (line.Contains("Def"))
                {
                    char delimiter = ' ';
                    string value = line;
                    string[] mySubstring = value.Split(delimiter);
                    string thisTrack = mySubstring[1];
                    string thisTrackName = mySubstring[5];
                    if (thisTrack != previousTrack)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(thisTrack);                            
                    }
                    previousTrack = mySubstring[1];
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my attempt to read more than 2 lines;

```
foreach (string line in _FileContents)
    {
        if (ppLine.Contains("Race"))
        {
            if (ppLine.Contains("TOD")) { }
        }
        else
        {
            if (pLine.Contains("Def"))
            {
                char delimiter = ' ';
                string value = line;
                string[] mySubstring = value.Split(delimiter);
                string thisTrack = mySubstring[1];
                string thisTrackName = mySubstring[5];
                if (thisTrack != previousTrack)
                {
                Console.WriteLine(thisTrack);                            
                }
                previousTrack = mySubstring[1];
                if(line.Contains("Spell")
                 { }
            }
        }
         ppLine =pLine;
         pLine = line;
    }
```

My intention is to read 3 lines here, but to still use split string on the second line which is pLine. Due to the way these lines are in the text file I am reading, if I read these 3 lines together then I will not be retrieving repeated data.

```
00000347: CEH r4  (Race) Race: 4 Post:     MTP:   TOD:2118
00000368: PHD r8  (Def) Phil   8/ 1/2016
00000406: PHD r8  (Spell)
```

Its the CEH I am capturing with my split string. I want all of the 3 letter abbreviations in the file and each group of these 3 lines has this info. These abbreviations are on lots of other lines but are not organised. My goal eventually will be to sort the List and output them to a comboBox in a winform.

My output reading 2 lines is as follows
DMD
CEH
PHD
STD
2BD
MTD
FCM
ELD
PMM
RUD
ADM
HSM
QIN
MNE
EMD
ASD
LQN
VCD
TQN
GZN
AJE
My desired output would be this with a keyword of "Spell" from the last line.

Comment: Could you add an example text file and the respective output you get and the one you want?

Comment: Does the file contain 3 line only? or many lines but in groups of three?

Comment: Here is an snippet from the text file, note that these are the two lines I am looking at. These two lines are repeated numerous times but its the CEH I am capturing with my split string. `00000347: CEH r4  (Race) Race: 4 Post:     MTP:   TOD:2118
00000368: PHD r8  (Def) Phil   8/ 1/2016
00000406: PHD r8  (Spellings)`

Comment: These lines are added to the original question now, sorry I didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using for loop, so that you can move through three lines at a time:

```
var fileContents = File.ReadLines("some path").ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileContents.Length - 2; i++)
        {
            var line1 = fileContents[i+0];
            var line2 = fileContents[i+1];
            var line3 = fileContents[i+2];
        }
```

My second try:

```
private static void Slider2()
    {
        var _FileContents = File.ReadAllLines("<path>");
        var previousLine = string.Empty;
        var lineBeforePrevious = string.Empty;
        foreach (var line in _FileContents)
        {
            // do something with line, previousLine and lineBeforePrevious

            // put some conditions around this
            lineBeforePrevious = previousLine;

            // put some conditions around this
            previousLine = line;
        }
    }
```

p.s. I cannot leave comments

Comment: Use'd better use `File.ReadAllLines("some path")` if you're not intented to stream it. Also `fileContents[i + 0];` would do better

Comment: @Zoran Basic Because the text file I am reading is hundreds of thousands lines long, and has lots of repeating data, I am searching for specific lines that are not in the same place throughout the text file. For this reason I have searched for three lines that contain certain keywords, that way it reads quickly and only returns the substring on the second line in that combination. Using the code I have already written, how can I make it search for three lines as oppose to 2 which I can already do successfully?

Comment: @Joroen thanks for the suggestions I have put them in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Though this task can be implemented just by using for(...) you can find lines you want to process using **ORegex**:

```
        var input = File.ReadLines("myFile").ToArray();

        var pTable = new PredicateTable<Word>();
        pTable.AddPredicate("def", x => x.Contains("Def"));
        pTable.AddPredicate("race", x => x.Contains("Race")); 
        pTable.AddPredicate("raceTod", x => x.Contains("Race") && x.Contains("TOD")); 

        var matches = new ORegex<string>("(?<g1>{race}{def})|(?<g2>{raceTod})", pTable).Matches(input)
        foreach(var m in matches)
        {
           var lines = m.Values.ToArray()
           var first = m.OCaptures["g1"];
           var second = m.OCaptures["g2"];
           //process your lines/groups
        }
```

This way you will be able not only get those lines, but also surrounding context, for example like this:

```
{race}{def}.{1,3}
```

you can get from 1 to 3 lines after your 'Race' and 'Def' lines.

Comment: I am not familiar with Regex and don't fully understand it, I am only a beginner c# programmer, I am trying to stay away from shortcuts like Linq and such until I fully understand programming itself. Thank you for your reply.